# Finding x root of a Transformation Matrix

Tags: matrices, 3d, transformation, programming, computer-algebra-systems

Let's say I have two boxes in 3D space. I know the Transformation of Box1 = $T^{world}_{box_0}$ and Box4 = $T^{box_0}_{box_4}$.

Our lovely designer want's me to write a tool that fills the the space between them for given amount of boxes (let's say 4  for demonstration) and each of them should transform such that $$T^{box_0}_{box_1} = T^{box_1}_{box_2} = T^{box_2}_{box_3} = T^{box_3}_{box_4}$$ and etc... So basically this should be my equation :

$$
T^{world}_{box_0} . T^{box_0}_{box_4} = T^{world}_{box_4}
$$

$$
T^{world}_{box_0} . T^{box_0}_{box_1}. T^{box_1}_{box_2}. T^{box_2}_{box_3}. T^{box_3}_{box_4} = T^{world}_{box_4}
$$

since all transformation between boxes should be equal :
$$
T^{box_0}_{box_1} = T^{box_1}_{box_2} = T^{box_2}_{box_3} = T^{box_3}_{box_4} = T_R
$$

$$
 T^{world}_{box_0} . T_R. T_R. T_R. T_R = T^{world}_{box_4}
$$

$$
T_R. T_R. T_R. T_R = T^{box_0}_{box_4}
$$
$$
(T^{box_0}_{box_4})^{1/4} = T_R
$$

So how do I calculate   $(T^{box_0}_{box_4})^{1/n}$  ?

Answer (score 1):

If your transformations $\mathbf{T}$ consist only of rotations and translations (and optionally global scaling), then the translation part is linear, and the rotation part easily solved via quaternions or bivectors.

See the Wikipedia [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion) article for how to convert between a quaternion and a rotation matrix.  (In a computer program, converting from a matrix to a quaternion or a bivector is best implemented in three ways, chosen at runtime depending which of the three diagonal entries has the largest magnitude.)

If $\mathbf{q}_0$ describes the initial orientation (rotation), and $\mathbf{q}_1$ the final orientation, then you can linearly interpolate between the two ($\lambda = 0 \dots 1$) to get an unnormalized quaternion,
$$\mathbf{q}_u = (1 - \lambda) \mathbf{q}_0 + \lambda \mathbf{q}_1$$
which you can directly convert to a rotation matrix.

---

More generally, a $4 \times 4$ 3D transformation matrix $\mathbf{T}$ can be described as
$$\mathbf{T} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\vec{u} & \vec{v} & \vec{w} & \vec{t} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right ]$$
where $\vec{u}$ is the $x$ axis unit vector after the transformation, $\vec{v}$ is the $y$ axis unit vector after the transformation, $\vec{w}$ is the $z$ axis unit vector after the transformation, and $\vec{t}$ is the translation.

You can find the corresponding orthonormal basis $[ \hat{u} ~ \hat{v} ~ \hat{w} ]$ from $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{u} &= \frac{\vec{u}}{\left\lVert \vec{u} \right\rVert} \\
\hat{v} &= \frac{\vec{\nu}}{\left\lVert \vec{\nu} \right\rVert}, \quad
\vec{\nu} = \vec{v} - \left( \vec{v} \cdot \hat{u} \right) \hat{u} \\
\hat{w} &= \hat{u} \times \hat{v} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Then,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\lambda_{uu} &= \vec{u} \cdot \hat{u} \\
\lambda_{vv} &= \vec{v} \cdot \hat{v} \\
\lambda_{vu} &= \vec{v} \cdot \hat{u} \\
\lambda_{ww} &= \vec{w} \cdot \hat{w} \\
\lambda_{wv} &= \vec{w} \cdot \hat{v} \\
\lambda_{wu} &= \vec{w} \cdot \hat{u} \\
\end{aligned} \right. \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\vec{u} &= \lambda_{uu} \hat{u} \\
\vec{v} &= \lambda_{vv} \hat{v} + \lambda_{vu} \hat{u} \\
\vec{w} &= \lambda_{ww} \hat{w} + \lambda_{wv} \hat{v} + \lambda_{wu} \hat{u} \\
\end{aligned} \right. $$
This way, you can do the pure rotation as described earlier, linearly interpolating both the translation and the six non-orthogonality parameters $\lambda$, between the two endpoints.

This does have a preferred order of axes (which in above is $x$, $y$, and finally $z$).  There are six possible orders – $xyz$, $xzy$, $yxz$, $yzx$, $zxy$, $zyx$ – and using the one that minimizes $\max\left( \lvert \lambda_{vu} \rvert, \lvert \lambda_{wv} \rvert, \lvert \lambda_{wu} \rvert \right)$ (i.e., minimizes the deviation from the basis set, choosing "the best" basis set as a result) might be a good idea.  (I suspect it yields "the best" results, unless additional information is available on how the initial and final transformations differ from an orthonormal matrix; but I have no proof of this.)